# Return the value of a column in another table matching a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have two tables that have 3 common columns however the rows are different, and a specific row for names which has duplicated values for other values of the other 2 columns which results in ambiguity form y reports.

My plan was to then use my first table, table A and just import in there using a function and through a calculated column (since table A and B both are updated weekly) the values from table B.

Now this is my attempt to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReturnFlag
(
    @name nvarchar(max)
    , @date smalldatetime
    , @DeptID nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS bit as 
begin 
    return [SpecialFlag]
    from TABLEB
    where [Name] = @name and [Date] = @date and [department] = @DeptID
end
```

However of course the syntax is incorrect.  Joining tables might be an option but again, both table A and B are updated weekly and I do not want to join this weekly. Table A and B are also used by other report software. My objective is to Add a computed column which uses the function above to get the corresponding value from table B. I have my 3 variables I need, since Name is not unique, but if I search in table B for name and date and department at the same time I will get a unique row and from there I can pull the value of the table B in the column SpecialFlag.  I believe that I am on the correct approach in the sense that I want this to be a one time fix, so then anytime I updated table A and B, the new computed column updates itself without me needing to run another query.

Comment: Are you looking for `return (select [SpecialFlag]
    from TABLEB
    where [Name] = @name and [Date] = @date and [department] = @DeptID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:
I tend to write scalar inline function without `begin`/`end`.  However, you can include them if you like:

```
create function dbo.ReturnFlag (
    @name nvarchar(max),
    @date smalldatetime,
    @DeptID nvarchar(max)
) returns bit as 
    return (select [SpecialFlag]
            from TABLEB
            where [Name] = @name and [Date] = @date and 
                  [department] = @DeptID
            );
```